# Get certain number of rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big table which has 700 millions of rows and dozens of columns. I need it to carry out a left join operation as the left table.

However, since it is so large, the time consumption is beyond affordable. So I'd like to split into few smaller tables and carry out the task in multiprocessing manner.

I know there is SSIS package is available for this, but I am constrained not to use it.

Also, I know it is a easy way to add a row id to each of the rows, but unfortunately, I cannot make change to the table.

So, may I know how to achieve my goal?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try `CTE`, it may work for you.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Hi, thanks for the hints, can you show me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CTE` and `row_number()`

```
;WITH cte_tbl AS
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [First Name]) AS RowNumber
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT * FROM cte_tbl
WHERE RowNumber < 100
```

You can fetch records for any range.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fetch-offset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)  if you need certain number of rows using sql-script.

like this:

```
SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name FROM big_table ORDER BY First Name OFFSET 15 ROWS;

SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name FROM big_table ORDER BY First Name OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a #temp table, and insert a subset of the records into it, then join to the #temp table. You can create an additional ID column in the #temp table as well for your needs.